# VB6 Paste issue

Tags: active-directory, vb6, paste

I have a weird issue.  I have a textbox where I paste info from our ticketing system where I hope to validate the user in Active Directory and other stuff.  Within the pasted information, I have a username and occasionally a user-id.  What is weird is, I parse the Last Name and First Name and store them as String Fields.  I pass those two fields to a function that does the Active Directory query.  I fail to make a hit in Active Directory.  But if I copy directly from the textbox to a form that accepts the first Name and Last name and call the same function I will make a hit from Active Directory.  I verified the exact length of names are correct.  As far as I know, I am not passing any white characters.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong or how to resolve this?

The code to put the `First Name` and `Last Name` to fields and then make the call to check Active Directory.  This is the part where I extract the names correctly, but can't find the entry in Active Directory.

```vb
    Idx = InStr(txtPaste.Text, "Voalte.")
    Work = Mid$(txtPaste.Text, Idx + 8, Len(txtPaste.Text))

    Temp = LTrim(Work)
   
    FirstName = RTrim(Left(Temp, InStr(1, Temp, " ") - 1))
    LastName = RTrim(Mid(Temp, InStr(Temp, " ") + 1))
      
    MsgBox "First Name: " & FirstName & " Len: " & Len(FirstName) & "   /   
    " & "Last Name: " & LastName & " Len: " & Len(LastName)
   
    txtADUserID.Text = GetID(LastName, FirstName)
    DoEvents
    MsgBox "ID: " & txtADUserID.Text
    txtADUserName.Text = FirstName & " " & LastName"
```

I have a form that accepts the first and last name and calls the `GetID` function.  This works

```vb
    fFirstname = txtFirstName.Text
    fLastName = txtLastName.Text

   
    txtADUserName.Text = fFirstname & Space(1) & fLastName
    txtADUserID.Text = GetID(fLastName, fFirstname)
    If Len(txtADUserID.Text) = 0 Then
       txtADUserID.Text = "User Not Found"
    End If
```

The `txtADUserName` and `TXTADUserID` are fields on the form.

This is the data I am parsing.

> IAM Application Request for Voalte One - v3.3
>
> Requested by Date:  9/29/2021 Requested for: - 1 -  John Doe (No
> Employee Number);
>
> Please provide the name of a someone you would like this user's access
> "mirrored" after in Voalte. Fred Flintstone

Comment: Is it possible that your filed is a password field where you have something like `****` and this is what you are copying?  Can you check the exact input in the AD function from both methods?  Do you have access to the source code?

Comment: Also, are you using English or some other language?  If you are using Unicode text, it is possible that there is an encoding issue somewhere.